# Set my lstlisting at the exact place in my code (like "h" for figure)

Tags: floats, listings, positioning

When using lstlisting, my displayed code is sent back on the top of my page. 
I would like to have the same kind of option as:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
...
\end{figure}
```

ie having displayed my code exactly where I put it in my latex code.

My current code for lstlisting is as follow:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float,style=Bash,caption={toto.bash},label=lst:logging]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Thanks!

**Second question:** 
How to display lstlisting on 2 followed pages, when the code is too long?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `figure` environment. Generally you don't need to use `figure` as `listings` provides a `float` option by itself. But for your case, you shouldn't use that either (as you do not want floating). The following code works as you wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Listing,language=c,escapechar=+] %% don't use float option here
+{public void}+ Method () {
  try {
    .. Original code
    .. After returning
  }
  catch (...) {
    .. After throwing
  }
  finally {
    .. After
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the code runs in to second page as well.

Comment: You were right! It comes from the float. Thank you for your help, fast and helpful. Have a nice day!

Comment: And what to do if you want to have the listing at a particular location, but want to avoid that it gets split over different pages?